# Keyboard interruptable blocking queue in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-2.x

It seems

```
import Queue

Queue.Queue().get(timeout=10)
```

is keyboard interruptible (ctrl-c) whereas

```
import Queue

Queue.Queue().get()
```

is not. I could always create a loop;

```
import Queue
q = Queue()

while True:
    try:
        q.get(timeout=1000)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
```

but this seems like a strange thing to do.

So, is there a way of getting an indefinitely waiting but keyboard interruptible Queue.get()?

Comment: Is the thread interruptible in any other way?

Comment: This is [Bug 1360](http://bugs.python.org/issue1360) which was closed as "won't fix".  The suggested workaround is to always specify a timeout if you need interruption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Queue` objects have this behavior because they lock using `Condition` objects form the `threading` module.  So your solution is really the only way to go.

However, if you really want a `Queue` method that does this, you can monkeypatch the `Queue` class.  For example:

```
def interruptable_get(self):
    while True:
        try:
            return self.get(timeout=1000)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
Queue.interruptable_get = interruptable_get
```

This would let you say

```
q.interruptable_get()
```

instead of

```
interruptable_get(q)
```

although monkeypatching is generally discouraged by the Python community in cases such as these, since a regular function seems just as good.

Comment: Ah, I see, a bad case of leaky abstractions*. Ahwell.

* http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: Why not subclass Queue, rather than monkey patching it?

Comment: Monkeypatching is better when you're receiving Queue objects that were instantiated and returned by some third-party code that you can't change, or possibly by some co-worker's code that you also can't change.  However, perhaps I should have used subclassing since that's probably not very common.

Comment: "`Queue` objects have this behavior because they lock using `Condition` objects form the `threading` module." I am not sure why this is the case. Can someone explain or point me to a resource that explains this behavior?

Comment: @joshreesjones, dimo414's comment is correct. See http://bugs.python.org/issue1360.

Answer (score 4):

This may not apply to your use case at all. But I've successfully used this pattern in several cases: (sketchy and likely buggy, but you get the point).

```
STOP = object()

def consumer(q):
    while True:
        x = q.get()
        if x is STOP:
            return
        consume(x)

def main()
    q = Queue()
    c=threading.Thread(target=consumer,args=[q])

    try:
        run_producer(q)
    except KeybordInterrupt:
        q.enqueue(STOP)
    c.join()
```